# How to pass a double in .getText()

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to create an app that converts celsius to Farhenheit. I want to pass float in .getText() but I'm unable to do so, It is giving me error which say cannot invoke .getText() on the primitive time float. Like I want to take the user input as double and then do the maths calculation. Can you please suggest me the approach to achieve this.

```
    changer = Float.parseFloat(textIn.getText().toString());
          textOut.setText(changer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   float celsius = Float.parseFloat(textIn.getText().toString());
   float farhenheit = (celsius * 1.8f) + 32.0f;
   textOut.setText(""+farhenheit);
```

in the case of converting from farhenheit to celsius:

```
case(R.id.radioButton2):
 float farhenheit = Float.parseFloat(textIn.getText().toString());
       float celsius = (( farhenheit - 32.0f ) x 5.0f ) / 9.0f;
       textOut.setText(""+celsius);
         break;
```

**NB  :** you should add `break;` at the end of each `case` in the `switch` bloc

Answer (score 2):

First you want edittext.gettext().tostring. And String Convert to double.

Answer (score 2):

```
txtProt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Protein);
p = txtProt.getText().toString();
protein = Double.parseDouble(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am currently not able to test this but i think this is the answer u need

```
String text = edittext.gettext.toString()
double f = double.parseDouble(text);
double f2 = do the math to calculate farhenheit
textview.settext(f2.toString())
```